# Sorting a file alphabetically by last name only

Tags: sort

I'm interested in sorting a text file that has entries with the First name and Last name in that order

[Ex]

John Doe

I'm interested in sorting the list by LAST name only.  Is this a job for sed or awk?  Can I modify the `sort`command to sort by the second word or LAST name only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
sort -k2 < your_file > out_file
```

`-k` specify the sort key; by default the field number where field are separated by blanks.

From  [`man sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/sort.1.html):

> ```
>   -k, --key=KEYDEF
>           sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
> ```
>
> KEYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position,
>   where
>          F is a field number and C a character position in the field;  both  are
>          origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither
>          -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a  field  are  counted  from  the
>          beginning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-let‐
>          ter ordering options  [bdfgiMhnRrV],  which  override  global  ordering
>          options  for  that key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the
>          key.

Example:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % cat test.txt
a a
b c
d r
k a
t 6
[romano:~/tmp] % sort -k2 < test.txt
t 6
a a
k a
b c
d r
```

Comment: Indeed it does, was just about to post the same thing, including moving the sort forward a few (5) characters with -k 2.5